# Multirow Tabs for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I commonly have 10+ tabs open per editor window which makes it tedious to scroll back and forth (or use ctrl+tab) to find the file I want.

Is there any way to have the [tabs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tabs) wrap?

Similar to Atom's [multirow-tabs](https://atom.io/packages/multirow-tabs).

**Update:** Looks like it is a work in [progress](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/106448).

Comment: As of version 1.53 multitabs are finally here!!! It took so long. Geez, it must have been so hard to implement, so congratulations to the VSC team!

Comment: I think Open Editors tab is more convinient https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_open-editors

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrYmKJXbRIA

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Version 1.53 includes [wrap tabs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53#_wrap-tabs)!

The new "Wrap Tabs" setting is a checkbox under `File > Preferences > Settings > Workbench > Editor Management`.

Alternatively, you can paste the following into your settings.json: `"workbench.editor.wrapTabs": true`

Comment: Also, `"workbench.editor.tabSizing"` must be set to `"fit"`

Answer (score 281):

> **UPDATE Feb 2021: In-built support for tabs-wrapping in VSCode v1.53.0+**
>
> - Just set the `workbench.editor.wrapTabs` to `true` in the settings.
> - I still use my configuration mentioned below to make tabs smaller as per my usage.

---

> **UPDATED 28 March 2020 for VSCode v1.43.2**
>
> - Fixed CSS for tab-close button
> - Added CSS for smaller bread-crumbs and acion-bar (at the right of tab-bar)

I do the following for multirow tabs in visual-studio-code (until there is official support or an easier solution):

**STEP 1:** Install the extension [VSCode Custom CSS](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css). (Check out the extension page for proper installation instruction. It's a bit of a hack as VSCode does not officially support altering internal CSS.)

**STEP 2:** Create a CSS file (say, *"/home/user/vscode/custom.css"*) and add the following contents:

```css
/* Following CSS to wrap the tab-bar into multiple rows: */

.tabs-and-actions-container > .monaco-scrollable-element {
  height: auto !important;
}

.tabs-and-actions-container > .monaco-scrollable-element > .tabs-container {
  height: auto !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/* Following CSS to make the tabs thinner/smaller (so that they take lesser vertical space): */

.monaco-workbench .part.editor > .content .editor-group-container > .title .tabs-container > .tab {
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    font-size: 0.8em;  /* smaller font-size for tab icons and label */
}

.monaco-workbench .part.editor > .content .editor-group-container > .title .tabs-container > .tab .label-name {
    font-size: inherit !important;  /* inherit updated font-size for label */
}


/* Following CSS for smaller close button on tabs: */

.monaco-workbench .part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.title .tabs-container>.tab>.tab-close {
    width: 20px;
}

.monaco-workbench .part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.title .tabs-container>.tab>.tab-close .action-label {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background-size: 12px;
}

.monaco-workbench .part.editor>.content .editor-group-container.active>.title .tabs-container>.tab>.tab-close .action-label.codicon {
    font-size: 12px;
}


/* OPTIONAL: Following CSS for smaller breadcrumbs (below tab-bar) */

.monaco-breadcrumbs {
    font-size:0.65em;
    opacity: 0.8;
    height:18px !important;
}
.tabs-breadcrumbs .breadcrumbs-control {
    height: 18px !important;
}
.monaco-workbench .symbol-icon.block {
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    min-height: 8px;
    min-width: 14px;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: contain;
}
.breadcrumbs-control .monaco-breadcrumb-item:before {
    min-width: 12px !important;
    height: 12px !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
}


/* OPTIONAL: Following CSS for smaller action-bar (beside the tab-bar) with menu, split, etc. */

.monaco-workbench .part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.title .editor-actions {
    height: 20px;
    padding:0;
}
.monaco-workbench .part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.title .editor-actions .action-label, .monaco-workbench .part.editor>.content .editor-group-container>.title .title-actions .action-label {
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    min-width: 14px;
    background-size: 8px;
}

.tabs-and-actions-container > .editor-actions > .monaco-toolbar > .monaco-action-bar > .actions-container {
    max-width:60px;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

**STEP 3:** Point the extension to your custom CSS. Open the VSCode **settings.json** *[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > "Open Settings(JSON)"]* and add the following lines (with your path to custom.css file):

```
"vscode_custom_css.imports": [
    "file:///home/user/vscode/custom.css"
],
"vscode_custom_css.policy": true
```

**STEP 4:** Make sure you have gone through the [VSCode Custom CSS](https://github.com/be5invis/vscode-custom-css) extension's readme and enabled it properly. You may have to reload VSCode. Also, edit the CSS as per your preferences!

**CREDIT:** This solution (link to extension and the CSS to wrap tab-bar into multi-lines) was originally posted by [Steven Laidlaw](https://github.com/stevenlaidlaw) in this [Github thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/70413). I just extended the CSS for smaller tabs.

Comment: Nice work dude. But I can't justify all that work just for this. MSFT should listen to their devs so this doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks, @BAR, desperately waiting for MSFT to enable this config without a hack! It's a lengthy hack but constantly working with many open tabs, I can't work without it anymore :)

Comment: Glad you posted this hack. Microsoft needs to add a multi-row feature to Visual Studio Code. These remarks on the plugin lead me to believe this solution is brittle: "NOTE: Every time after Visual Studio Code is updated, please re-enable Custom CSS. NOTE: Every time you change the configuration, please re-enable Custom CSS."

Comment: perfect naming: wrap instead multiline.
Thanks buddy, I'm fkd up of searching

Answer (score 35):

In addition to the setting I mentioned below, now (in Insiders v1.83, will be in Stable early October 2023) is the ability to put **pinned tabs** in their own upper row.  See this setting:

```
Workbench > Editor > Pinned Tabs on Separate Row
// this is disabled by default right now
```

Pinned tabs will go on their own row regardless of the `Workbench > Editor: Wrap Tabs` setting.

[image: demo of pinned tabs in their own row]

In addition, dragging a tab to the pinned row will pin that tab.  And dragging a pinned tab to another row of tabs will un-pin that tab.

---

Significant progress has been made on this issue [Allow tabs to wrap to multi-line](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70413)  and the feature is now in v1.53 Stable:
[image: wrap tabs demo]

As seen in the demo, you can even drag tabs from one row to another.  There is currently no limit on the number of rows until the editor itself gets too small.

You enable this functionality with

`workbench.editor.wrapTabs: true`  or

`Workbench > Editor: Wrap Tabs` in the Settings gui.

A couple of notes from [testing tab wrapping](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114827):

- make sure you have configured `workbench.editor.tabSizing: fit` (this will make the last tab fill the entire row for a more homogeneous look when tabs wrap) [ed. note: you can still use `shrink`, it just doesn't look as nice]
- if the space for the editor or editor toolbar becomes too small, wrapping turns off automatically and turns on again when the size get's larger
- you can still drag and drop tabs around even when they wrap
- you can still pin a tab and it shows pinned in the beginning of the tabs
- when tabs wrap, the tab.border color is not only applied to the right of each tab but also below to separate tabs from each other

Also, depending on your color theme, consider modifying these settings:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "tab.border": "#fff6",
  "titleBar.border": "#fff6",
  "editorGroupHeader.tabsBorder": "#647c64",
}
```

to set off the borders of each tab.

---

---

By the way, **pinned tabs** are coming to v1.46.  More on their functionality:  [v1.46 release notes: pinned tabs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#pin-tabs)

Answer (score 5):

Since multirow tabs are still not officialy supported in VSCode, I wanted to bring a feature request to your attention that I just posted on their github.
Instead of always wrapping tabs to a new row I propose to have them laid out on rows that are completely independent from each other. The user decides, they can mix short rows with long rows that still require scrolling. See the details here:

[github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80510](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80510)

My proposed solution certainly requires more work than unceremoniously wrapping tabs to a new row but in return it lets the user organize their tabs in a way that could increase productivity.

Answer (score 3):

Head over to vs code settings and search for wrap tabs. Check this checkbox to allow tab wrapping.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just played with the vscode developer tools console, and looks like this CSS will be enough to do that if incorporated with an extension:

```
.tabs-and-actions-container .monaco-scrollable-element {
   height: auto;
} 
.tabs-and-actions-container .monaco-scrollable-element .tabs-container {
   flex-wrap: wrap; flex: 1 1 auto;
   height: auto;
}
```

You can add this code to `file:///C:/Users/[username]/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.main.css` file to use it until your application updates.

> **Note:** When you add this to `workbench.main.css` file, VSCode will alert that the integrity of VScode is corrupted, ignore that message. VSCode will function as before because it's a CSS change (if any javascript doesn't use some positions of the tabs, or something else).

Otherwise as @Bene said, this is a restricted area by VSCode development team. They say:

> ## Restrictions
>
> There are certain restrictions we impose upon extensions.
> Here are the restrictions and their purposes.
>
> ### No DOM Access
>
> Extensions have no access to the DOM of VS Code UI. You
> cannot write an extension that applies custom CSS to VS Code or adds
> an HTML element to VS Code UI.
>
> At VS Code, we're continually trying to optimize use of the underlying
> web technologies to deliver an always available, highly responsive
> editor and we will continue to tune our use of the DOM as these
> technologies and our product evolve. To ensure that extensions cannot
> interfere with the stability and performance of VS Code, and that we
> can continue to improve the DOM of VS Code without breaking existing
> extensions, we run extensions in an Extension Host process and prevent
> direct access to the DOM.

@ https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview#no-dom-access

Comment: Unfortunately not possible https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview#no-dom-access

Comment: @Bene I guess it's possible but VSCode team don't want you to do it. Otherwise you can force-edit "workbench.main.css". I guess this guy has done it: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kcpoipoi.sushi-buffet

Comment: WARNING: make a backup of workbench.main.css. It corrupted my installation for even editing it. Undid the edits but still corrupted.

Comment: Yes it says that because the integrity of workbench.main.css file looks corrupted to the application when you add that CSS. Perhaps I should note that too.

Answer (score 0):

I have found/developed a solution to display pinned tabs in their own row.. It's an **addition** to what people might be using already, not the answer to this thread per se.

Original reply on **github**: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98160#issuecomment-989276052

- `vscode` v1.62.3
- extension: `Custom CSS and JS Loader` v6.0.2

`settings.json`

```json
{
  "workbench.editor.wrapTabs": true,

  "git.decorations.enabled": false,
  "workbench.editor.decorations.badges": false,
  "workbench.editor.decorations.colors": false,

  "vscode_custom_css.imports": ["file:///C:/temp/VScode/custom.css"],
  "vscode_custom_css.policy": true
}
```

p.s. In config above I also disabled some `git` stuff from tabs to make them more readable.. not sure if it affects other places, use with caution.

`custom.css`

```css
.tabs-container {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

.tabs-container::before,
.tabs-container::after {
  content: "" !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  order: 1 !important;
}

.tab {
  display: flex !important;
}

.tab:not(.sticky) {
  order: 1 !important;
}
```

Result (`gif`):

[image]