# Display tabs in multiple rows

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I opened many tabs, most of them go hidden.
Finding one from them is so tedious.
Are there any extensions that keep them to appear in multiple rows?

Comment: Found the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462777/multirow-tabs-for-vscode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multirow Tabs for VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462777/multirow-tabs-for-vscode)

Comment: Yep. It did. ;-)

Comment: Flagged it for you because you didn't have access to flags, +1 for figuring out your issue :)