# How do I pin a Pinned tab in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code and thought a pinned tab would remain where it was pinned (it was the top left tab).

However, if I open up a bunch more tabs and start tabbing to those, my pinned tab disappears off to the left somewhere.

How do I pin it in place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open files always in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713405/open-files-always-in-a-new-tab)

Answer (score 2):

You can edit "Workbench > Editor: Wrap Tabs" setting in the **Settings**

1. Open **Settings**:

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>, (comma)</kbd> (<kbd>command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>, (comma)</kbd> on Mac), or by

     - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Mac)
     - Type "user settings"
     - Click on "Preferences: Open Settings"
2. Then in the **Settings**:

   - Type "wrap tabs" in the search
   - Click on the checkbox for "Workbench > Editor: Wrap Tabs"

---

Alternatively, add the following line directly in the **settings.json**:

- "workbench.editor.wrapTabs": true

---

You can pin the current tab with the following key shortcut:

- **Windows**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- **Mac**: <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Or, right-click on the title of the tab, then select Pin from the drop-down menu

Answer (score 2):

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61903472/836330

[image: pinned tabs in a separate row demo]

```
Workbench > Editor > Pinned Tabs on Separate Row
// this is disabled by default right now
```