# How to display more files on top tab in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to configure VS Code to increase the number of files that are able to be displayed across the tabs at the top?

There are currently just 4 files<sup>1</sup> visible in that top area, but ~10 would be ideal:

[image]

#### Example

Sublime text uses smaller font on file names (despite similar font size of the code itself), and so allows about twice as much space for displaying files:

[image]

#### Current work around

I hit <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd> a few times to quickly survey open files.

#### Ideas

Perhaps open files could be quickly surveyed (without key presses) if it is possible to:

- Expand the area to have more than 1 row of files
- Configure VS Code to show only part of the filename
- Use smaller font on the file names (not the code itself), similar to sublime text
- Something else?

---

<sup>1</sup> The habits of using long file names, and having a lot of files open at the same time don't help, I'm aware of that.

Comment: you can show the **Open Editors** View in the Explorer bar, use the `...` menu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multirow Tabs for VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462777/multirow-tabs-for-vscode)

Comment: @AdamL thanks for this, it solved the problem. I wonder if it is indeed a duplicate though, since although multiple rows of tabs solves the problem, there may be other ways (e.g. smaller font like sublime text). I think for this reason the question would be best left open, in case it prompts other answers that may suit others better than mulitrow tabs, depending on their circumstances/preferences. What do you think?

Comment: @stevec Smaller fonts are covered, too :)

Answer (score 2):

### The approach where you just use more space

```json
"workbench.editor.wrapTabs": true,
```

(see also [Multirow Tabs for VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42462777/11107541))

### The approach where you make things take less space

##### workbench.editor.tabSizing

There's the `"workbench.editor.tabSizing": "shrink"` setting value, which is documented as so:

> Allow tabs to get smaller when the available space is not enough to show all tabs at once.

(the default value for `workbench.editor.tabSizing`) is `"fit"`.

##### workbench.editor.wrapTabs

As other have mentioned, there's the `workbench.editor.wrapTabs` setting, which you can find more about in this Q&A: [Multirow Tabs for VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42462777/11107541).

TL;DR from the setting's description:

> Controls whether tabs should be wrapped over multiple lines when exceeding available space or whether a scrollbar should appear instead. This value is ignored when `#workbench.editor.showTabs#` is disabled.

##### git.decorations.enabled

You can shave a few pixels by disabling git decorations if you're working on a git project (of course- this is only if you're okay with disabling git decorations). Git decorations add letter indicators to the tab handles that summarize what has changed about those files. Ex. "M" means the file has been modified, and "A" means it has been added.

```json
"git.decorations.enabled": false
```

##### workbench.editor.tabCloseButton (VS Code pre-1.85)

You can shave a few pixels by disabling the close button on tabs (if you're okay with that (you'll still be able to close the tab with the associated keyboard shortcut, or by middle-clicking the tab handle)):

```json
"workbench.editor.tabCloseButton": "off"
```

##### workbench.editor.tabActionCloseVisibility and workbench.editor.tabActionUnpinVisibility (VS Code 1.85+)

```json
"workbench.editor.tabActionCloseVisibility": false,
"workbench.editor.tabActionUnpinVisibility": false,
```

##### workbench.editor.showTabs

If your aim is really to declutter, you can take the hardcore/nuclear route and do:

```json
"workbench.editor.showTabs": false, // VS Code pre-1.85
"workbench.editor.showTabs": "off", // VS Code 1.85+
```

Et voila! Now the tab handles take up *zero space* because they're *gone* :D (and you can navigate tabs using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (that's on Windows and Linux- not sure what it is on MacOS), or by using the Explorer view's "Open Editors" section (you might need to enable it first under the three-dots menu))