Keep pinned files displayed in vscode
In vscode, I have pinned a file, main.tex, it now appears as pinned on the opened editors list at the top of the screen:

But, as I have many files opened when a file "too on the right" is opened, the pinned tab is hidden :

Is it possible to set the display so that this tab is still displayed ? It would be like this (photomontage):

The pinned tab is still present on the left of the tabs.

I don't know if what you want is supported, but you can do something like this where the pinned tabs get their own row:  https://i.sstatic.net/CU8xtjar.png

how have you managed to do it? I only found the setting Workbench > Editor: Wrap Tabs, which results in a huge heap of 4 lines of tabs (which takes 1/4 of the screen, as I have many tabs opened !)
Edit: see the answer by Timothy G. below

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61903472/836330

You can make pinned tabs have their own row by setting workbench.editor.pinnedTabsOnSeparateRow to true:
{
   "workbench.editor.pinnedTabsOnSeparateRow": true
}

This will keep your pinned tabs from scrolling with the rest of the other tabs.  Though if you have too many pinned tabs, you will have to scroll through them as well.


thanks for your answer, it takes a little more space on the screen, but not that much, so that's good enough for me ;) (even though the possibility of having it on a single line as in my initial post would be optimal !)
